# php txt string compare array compare

Tags: php, string, compare

```
$c = '4432';
$word = file_get_contents('1234.txt');
$value = explode(" ",$word);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   if ($value[$i] = $c){
      echo $value[$i];
      break;
    }
}
```

File `1234.txt` content:

```
1234 789 
4432 998
5532 999
```

How to compare 4432 and get value 789 separately? I need:

```
if $c is 1234 then get 789 value
if $c is 4432 then get 998 value
if $c is 5532 then get 999 value
```

Now my code only can get 1234 or 4432 or 5532.

Thank you.

Comment: How to compare 4432 with what element? array? key? value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to get the expected results using `file()` and `explode()` functions:

```
<?php
$match = '4432';

$file = file('1234.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($file as $line) {
    $words = explode(" ", $line);
    if ($words[0] == $match) {
        echo $words[1];
        break;
    }       
}
?>
```

Additional notes:

- Function `file_get_contents()` reads entire file into a string, but `file()` returns the file's content into an array.
- [Comparison operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in PHP is `==` (`===`), not `=`.